# Crash set variable extension Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I got a crash when i try to set a variable inside a extension:

```
extension String {
 var index: Int {
    get {
        return self.index
    }
    set {
        self.index = newValue
    }
 }
}

var o: String = "tre"


o.index = 87 // crash here
println(o.index) // Even here
```

i tried everything, without any success.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just wondering, in what manner does `index` have anything to do with `String`? IOW, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wanted to add a new property named index or whatever, in the String class. It sounds like impossible. It doesn't matter thanks anyway.

Comment: Please do not add an extension method to a class unless from the name alone it is easily understood what it does. `String` is a particularly bad place to ass `index` since they may contain variable length characters.

Comment: In fact the sample code was an example, in fact i wanted to add a Int inside a UIViewController extension, but i had the same issue.

Comment: In the case of `UIViewController` just create a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add new stored variables to a type using extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a loop by infinitely setting or getting a property.

You cannot add new stored properties with extension, only computed ones that are not backed by a property.

Comment: Don't know why there is no compiler errors/warnings for this, but you could do the same in Objective-C if setting/getting property inside setter/getter of it without using instance variable directly.

Comment: There is no compiler error because he hasn't declared a stored property, only a computed one that refers to itself.